# Can MS report data be redirected?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Can MS report data be redirected?

I have a MS report control and I want to be able to take the data that would go to the (MS report control) UI in some cases to instead of being viewed, go to a file.

I don't see where that can be done but want to ask if anyone knew a way.

I tried look at the datasource from the report but I don't see where you can get the data back.

Comment: do you want the raw data or in a byte array of a specific rendered format (pdf, excel, html,etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

As the comment is suggesting you can programmatically render the report directly out to one of reporting services export format using the web service. There's an example [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160928012839/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/bsherwin/archive/2007/04/29/112094.aspx) which renders out a pdf stream.